# Taxonomy terms are not translated in an exposed filters block

Tags: drupal, internationalization, drupal-6, drupal-views

in my view's exposed filters block the taxonomy terms are showed only in the original language version (in English).

- Vocabulary is set to `Localize terms`.
- The terms are translated via Translation Table.
- All the other content (Views, nodes, translated strings etc.) is showed correctly (in German).

I'd expect them to appear in current language, however.

[image]

Here for instance, I'd expect to have German `Sommer 10` instead of English `Summer 10`.

Do You have any idea how to solve it?

*I use Drupal 6 and Views 2.10*

Comment: Although this post is a bit old, did you solve this problem? How did you do it? 2 years later this is still an issue for many people. Can you please provide a step by step answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [a patch to make taxonomy terms appear translated](http://drupal.org/node/346028#comment-2769734).

Unfortunately, it seems that the it's not a bug but just a not (yet) implemented feature (see [this](http://drupal.org/node/277909#comment-905780) and [that](http://drupal.org/node/277909#comment-905987)).

> (...) *The reason that there is a difference in node behavior is that the module you're using for taxonomy translation modifies the node. It would have to modify the view as well. Drupal core doesn't support translating vocabulary. I am happy to (...) make sure it has the capability to help with Views translation, but you must understand that this is:
>
>   1) not automatic
>
>   2) not views' responsibility.*